# How Can I use the URLConnection class when internet speed is slow

Tags: android, urlconnection

How Can I use the `URLConnection` class when internet speed is slow? I ask this question because when I use [this code](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89) in a really server with high speed Internet I can get the input string successfully from the server. But when I test the same code with slow Internet the code can not send a request to the server and it happens a `catch`. Now my question is how can I connect to the server while my Internet speed is very slow?

Comment: U should just change the timeout of your request to be much longer and you ll be giving some time to your request to be routed and get it response.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest using okhttp ( http://square.github.io/okhttp/ )
Second you should adjust your timeouts